# Infinite loop when joining threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, functor

I'm trying to use the `ThreadPool` class that is available [here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h)

Unfortunately, this class has been designed in such a way to create its threads at creation time and join them in the destructor. To make it more flexible and to be able create threads several times in it, I have added the following function to this class:

```
void join_all() {
        condition.notify_all();
        for (std::thread &worker : workers) {
            worker.join(); // I get blocked here
        }
    }
```

However, with this change, when running the following main:

```
int main() {

ThreadPool pool(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        pool.enqueue([i]() {
            std::cout << "HELLO " << i << std::endl;
        });
    }
    pool.join_all(); // here I am blocked
    return 0;

}
```

My main thread will be blocked inside `join_all` function while trying to join the first thread.

What's the proper way to write `join_all()` function which would allow me to keep using the pool without terminating it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question. Presumably you need to set `stop` in the pool

Comment: Where is the infinite loop? Does it get stuck in an infinite loop or does it block somewhere?

Comment: The code shown doesn't correspond to the `ThreadPool` code in the link.  Note the usage of the `bool ThreadPool::stop` member in the linked code.

Comment: @user4581301 The program is running but after all the prints get stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @G.M. Doesn't correspond in what sense? How should it be written?

Comment: @BulGali Why you want to write a `join_all()` method yourself??? The threads are joining in the destructor of the `ThreadPool` class.

Comment: @Gupta As I wrote in the last line, I want to keep using the pool for further applications which require the finish of the previous ones.

Comment: The correct way to do what (I think) you want is to manage the lifetime of the `ThreadPool` instance such that it stays in scope/available for as long as you want to use it.  After that just let its destructor signal and terminate the workers.

Comment: I have edited the Q to be more specific about the debugging details. I think it can be reopened now.

Answer (score 1):

The `ThreadPool` class already joins the threads on its destructor. But if you want to have your own `join_all()` function (for any reason), you should set the `stop` variable as well:

```
   void join_all() 
   {
      {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
         stop = true;
      }
      condition.notify_all();
      for (std::thread &worker : workers) {
         worker.join();
      }
   }
```

**Warning:** Now, you should be careful about double joining on your threads. So, what I propose is to check the threads before joining (e.g. in the destructor):

```
   for (std::thread &worker : workers)
   {
      if (worker.joinable())
      {
         worker.join();
      }
   }
```

With these changes, the code works without any infinite loops.

Comment: Thanks, Gupta. Where would you set stop to false if you'd wish to use the pool again? Otherwise, if stop is set to true, enqueue can not be used.

Comment: @BulGali In that case, I propose to have a new method `add_threads(int size)` and move the whole code from constructor to this method. At the beginning of the method, you can set `stop = false`.